# scan a barcode with smartphone camera from a web page

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, smartphone

I would like to scan a barcode with smartphone camera from a web page
here is the link. the problem is how can I store a scanned text from this link in inputbox from the webpage?

http://example.azurewebsites.net/desc.html?code={CODE}">Scan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use PHP for this problem.
Your variable is `code` so in PHP you would do something like this:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
```

to display it in your input box just simply add the value attribute:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['code']; ?>">
```